# EJS/Javascript - For every 3rd entry, write X

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, view, ejs

I'm currently learning to write EJS views with NodeJS. Currently I'm making a products page that has three items per row, with all the items being pulled from a MongoDB. I have about 11 items for testing at the moment. However, I'm running in to trouble on how to write something specific. After every **third** item, I need to write the following.

```
</div>                                       
<div class="row">
```

My current loop looks like this. Any help is appreciated!

```
<% data.forEach(function(item) { %>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <div class="item">
            <!-- Use the below link to put HOT icon -->
            <!-- <div class="item-icon"><span>HOT</span></div> -->
            <!-- Item image -->
            <div class="item-image">
                <a href="/p/<%= item.id %>"><img src="/img/items/<%= item.id %>.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"/></a>
            </div>
            <!-- Item details -->
            <div class="item-details">
                <!-- Name -->
                <h5><a href="/p/<%= item.id %>"><%= item.title %></a></h5>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <!-- Para. Note more than 2 lines. -->
                <p><%= item.desc %></p>
                <hr />
                <!-- Price -->
                <div class="item-price pull-left"><%= item.price %></div>
                <!-- Add to cart -->
                <div class="pull-right"><a href="/#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Add to Cart</a></div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<% }); %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will print for every third starting with the third iteration.

```
<% data.forEach(function(item, i) { %>
  // Stuff
  <% if((i + 1) % 3 === 0) %>
    </div>                                       
    <div class="row">
  <% } %>
<% }) %>
```